# Create eternal history in TCSH

Tags: bash, translate, tcsh

In my Linux systems which run bash I have an 'eternal history' file, which keeps any new command I click in:

```
export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%s "
PROMPT_COMMAND="${PROMPT_COMMAND:+$PROMPT_COMMAND ; }"'echo $$ $USER "$(history 1)" >> ~/.bash_eternal_history'
```

My question is how to translate this into tcsh environment?

Comment: I don't believe this is off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a mini-guide [here](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20070715091413640).

In short, you need to add this to your `.tcshrc` file:

```
set history = 2000          # History remembered is 2000
set savehist = (2000 merge) # Save and merge with existing saved 
set histfile = ~/.tcsh_history
```

and this to you `.logout` file:

```
history -S
```